# how to Access to nested items in JSON with foreach PHP?

Tags: php, json

I have the following JSON structure

```
{"Id":"1","Persons":[{"Name":"Carl","Time":"00:00:03","info":"","Timeext":"","Timeout":"","Timein":""}, {"Name":"Carl","Time":"00:00:03","info":"","Timeext":"","Timeout":"","Timein":""}{"Name":"Luis","Time":"00:00:08","info":"","Timeext":"","Timeout":"","Timein":""}]}
```

How I can have acces or read the item inside the nest? For example if I just want the value of time for Carl or all information about Carl. Till now I just can get without a problem the single item  in the collection 'Id'. The rst nested items not.
I tryed with json_decode like this:

```
if( $_POST ) {

            $arr['Id'] = $_POST['Id'];
            $arr['NP'] = $_POST['NP'];

            $jsdecode = json_decode($arr);

            foreach ($jsdecode as $values){
                echo $values->Time;
            }
```

Can PLEASE somebody help me?

Comment: use var_dump or print_r and check the array elements with their values

Comment: Is the JSON sent as the full body of the request, or is it url-encoded?

Answer (score 5):

```
if( $_POST ) {

        $arr['Id'] = $_POST['Id'];
        $arr['NP'] = $_POST['NP'];

        $jsdecode = json_decode($arr,true);

        foreach ($jsdecode as $values){
            echo $values->Time;
        }
```

Adding 'true' to json_decode converts it to array

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your answer! I tried like you said but I don't get the correct result. But at least the jqury answer me undefined, before was nothing :)

Comment: Like this I am doing in the client side: success:  function (data) {
             $(data).each(function(i, v){ 
     alert( v.Time);
    })
                
            },

Answer (score 1):

You are processing it correct , Just add `true` as the second parameter to `json_decode` which will be converted to an ***Array*** like

```
$jsdecode = json_decode($arr,true);
```